# Autoscaling using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I have come up with an template but it shows an error `Template format error: [/Resources/MyServerGroup] resource definition is malformed` I have tried solving it but unable to. Please do review the template also I am new to this there might be some mistakes. I have taken help from this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  SourceStackName:
    Description: "Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "noob-vpc"
Resources:
  ec2instance:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: sg-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-PublicSubnet"
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref webserver
 
  webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: gn-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
  MyServerGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZones: us-east-2
    LaunchConfigurationName:
      Ref: ec2instance
    MinSize: '2'
    MaxSize: '3'
    # LoadBalancerNames:
    # - Ref: LB
  MyAsGroupWithNotification:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZones: us-east-2
    LaunchConfigurationName:
      Ref: myLCOne
    MinSize: '0'
    MaxSize: '2'
    DesiredCapacity: '1'
    NotificationConfigurations:
    - TopicARN:
        Ref: topic1
      NotificationTypes:
      - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH
      - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR
      - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE
      - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR
```

Secondly Please check if I am not missing anything. I have read the documentation and come up with this template. I have another template VPC inn which I have created the subnets and imported their values into this template

VPC:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.2.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  SubnetD:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.3.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  RouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetC

  SubnetDRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetD
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
Outputs:
  vpcID:
    Description: VPC id
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-VpcID"
  SubnetA:
    Description: public subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetA
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetA"
  SubnetB:
    Description: public subnet 2
    Value: !Ref SubnetB
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetB"
  SubnetC:
    Description: priavte subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetC
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetC"
  SubnetD:
    Description: private subnet 2
    Value: !Ref SubnetD
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SubnetD"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alignment was wrong for the `MyServerGroup` and `MyAsGroupWithNotification` resource. From a brief glance it appears correct but it is not possible to run as it references another stack.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  SourceStackName:
    Description: "Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "noob-vpc"
Resources:
  ec2instance:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: sg-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-PublicSubnet"
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref webserver
 
  webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: gn-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
  MyServerGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
        AvailabilityZones: us-east-2
        LaunchConfigurationName:
          Ref: ec2instance
        MinSize: '2'
        MaxSize: '3'
        # LoadBalancerNames:
        # - Ref: LB
  MyAsGroupWithNotification:
      Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZones: us-east-2
        LaunchConfigurationName:
          Ref: myLCOne
        MinSize: '0'
        MaxSize: '2'
        DesiredCapacity: '1'
        NotificationConfigurations:
        - TopicARN:
            Ref: topic1
          NotificationTypes:
          - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH
          - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR
          - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE
          - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR
```

Comment: I have updated the question added my vpc template. It now shows `Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [topic1] in the Resources block of the template` and honestly I am figuring out how to initialize topic1. Please help!!

Comment: This is from calling Ref: topic1, there’s no parameter or resource with that name

Comment: I get it but can you help me figure out how to create it. Its main function is to create notification. I have used this source https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html. The code is taken from autoscaling group with notification. Please help me configure the notification part

Comment: You can remove NotificationConfigurations it is not required, it is to trigger aSNS publication for instance events

Comment: Having error in `MyAsGroupWithNotification` the error is `Value of property AvailabilityZones must be of type List of String`

Comment: You’ve specified regions it should be availability zones as lists I.e. us-east-2a, us-east-2b

Comment: I can't give network interface in ec2 lunch configuration while autoscaling? `Encountered unsupported property NetworkInterfaces`. I have updated the code which I am running

Comment: The property here does not exist. Subnets are in the autoscaling group, security groups are here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-securitygroups